# Can't convert Java code to Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to change a project's code base from Java to Kotlin. Doing this by right click on class/package and select `Convert Java File to Kotlin File`.

For most of the classes it works fine but for some the change doesn't happen and I don't get any error/warning message.

I'm using Android Studio 3.6.1

Comment: I'm not sure the actual issue because it is not enough information to answer but one possibility is you should install Kotlin plugin into Android studio, first. 
Did you install the Kotlin plugin into Android studio?

Comment: yes, already have the plugin. The issue is that nothing happens when I try to convert from java to kotlin and I don't get any warning/error message to see what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

you keyboar shortcut ctrl+alt+shift+k for linux. I dont know about mac/windows. But you can check from file->settings->keymap "Convert Java File To Kotlin File". If you press the keyboard set inside java class, it automatically converts the whole class.